# Using the value of a default field of Interface inside the classes that implement the interface

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-10.0

I have an `interface` and I am trying to have a `default property` in it.
So I tried this:

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    string DoSomething();
    
    MySpecialClass ClassData {get => new ClassData(); set{} }
}
```

then I have a bunch of `classes` that implement this `interface` but there is nothing special about that `ClassData` field to be different for each of the classes that implement it so I do **NOT** want to keep copy pasting it in each future class that's why I am trying to do a default implementation of it in the interface.

However in **some** of the concrete classes I may want to actually use the value of that field. So my question is how can I do that?
so for example:

```
SomeClass s = new SomeClass();
s.ClassData = "some data I want to use later maybe...";

public class SomeClass: IMyInterface
{
    public string DoSomething()
    {
        // Here I want to have access to that field ClassData from the interface so I can do things to it.
    }   
}
```

My **problem **is I don't have access inside the implementation of that interface to use that default property value I just set above.
**How can I acheive something like that?**

I tried calling it with `this` too but no luck.

Comment: Nomenclature: this is not a "field", but a "property"

Answer (score 1):

To call a default interface method (or here property) on an type that does not override that method, you have to cast to the interface type first: `((IMyInterface)this).ClassData`.

However, if you override that property, you will no longer be able to access that default implementation on that class. That's why the docs recommend introducing a `protected static` version that would always be able to provide the default, even after the default version is overriden: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/advanced-topics/interface-implementation/default-interface-methods-versions#extend-the-default-implementation

Note that DIMs aren't really "intended" for this kind of scenario, and are really meant to provide a way to add methods to interfaces without breaking compatibility with old implementations. The suggestion is to either use an abstract class for this, or if that's not an option, static methods on the interface.

Comment: So are you saying I should add a protected static in front that property then? I read your paragraphs and still not sure what I should be doing .